# What grains and/or technique will result in a thin pancake with a artisan bread type structure?

Tags: frying-pan

I have tried whole wheat flour, using more fat, using more liquid, but not 
getting good texture - usually just a weaker pancake. I'm trying to get a thin pancake with texture that is hearty,somewhat porous and tender.

Comment: What's a "artisan bread type structure" ?

Comment: Have you considered making injera?  It's tender, spongy and hearty.  Not the easiest thing to make, though.  Sourdough pancakes might be an alternative, or even a yeast-based pancake

Answer (score -1):

I think you cannot have both thin and bread-like structure.

AFAIK, To have a bread-like structure the batter/dough needs to develop some gluten in it.

Usually pancakes do not have a bread texture, they are, erm, a pan cake.

The batter is just mixed, and most recipes say to not over mix the batter.

You can try buckwheat, it has a rustic quality to it that can be seen as "bread-like".